# monitoring facebook posts with graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a task to develop a social media monitoring tool for my diploma.

First I was using search method with type "post", but now with release of Graph API 2.0 it was marked as deprecated and I cannot find any method for my goal.

I also saw documentation for Keyword Insights API and it is just what I need, but it is open only for media publishers.

Is there any method or maybe streaming endpoint (like Twitter Streaming API) to monitor Facebook posts?

Comment: No, there is no such endpoint with Graph API v2.0

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Provider Post API for getting facebook Posts

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/posts?access_token={your facebook access token}

Click here for more detail [Facebook Post API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed)

Comment: I guess I can monitor posts of a specific user with this method. But I need to get all public posts that match specified search pattern.

Comment: that api provide filter option as a parameter so you able to filter posts

Comment: Yes, I see it. But I need to get all public posts from various users, not the one user.

Comment: The same problem here. I solved data monitoring by API for campaigns, but not for organic behaviour.